# regarding returning values modified through a function

Tags: r

I am trying to use a function that modifies the values in an array, here is the function

```
testReturn<-function(a){
for (i in 1:6){
a[i]<-a[i]+i
}
return(a)
}
```

The following is the running result

```
> a<-rep(0,6)
> testReturn(a)
  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> a
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Looks like the function itself successfully modifies array `a`. But the returned `a` array still keeps the same. How to do that correctly?

Comment: R passes by copy, not by reference. To get the behaviour you require, you'll need to do:  a<-testReturn(a);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the function back to `a`:

```
a <- testReturn(a)
```

Like @Aditya said, R passes by value, not by reference, in contrast to how for example subroutines work in Fortran. As soon as you make a change to `a` inside the function, a copy of `a` is made inside the function. This new version is only relevant within the scope of the function. The way to pass this on to the environment outside the function is to use the return argument via `return()`.

After returning the result, you still need to assign it to a new variable in the global environment. In the example you showed, the object was not assigned to any new object, but instead just printed to the screen. To assign it to the global value of `a`, just use the code I listed above.